# Select info from table with multiple grouping and highest date

Tags: mysql

My table looks something like this, and `CURDATE() = 2021-03-31`

```
id |itemNo|startDate  |endDate    |UOM  |Price |
---+------+-----------------------+-----+------+
1  |1AY   |2018-02-01 |NULL       |PCS  |4.10  |
2  |1AY   |2021-02-01 |NULL       |PCS  |3.50  | <
3  |2ZX   |2021-01-02 |2021-03-01 |BTL  |11.20 | 
4  |3GH   |2021-04-01 |NULL       |TIN  |4.00  |
5  |3GH   |2019-01-01 |NULL       |TIN  |3.00  | <
6  |2ZX   |2021-01-01 |NULL       |BTL  |10.00 | <
7  |2ZX   |2019-01-01 |NULL       |BTL  |13.00 |
8  |1AY   |2021-02-01 |NULL       |BOX  |6.50  | <
9  |1AY   |2021-01-01 |NULL       |BOX  |6.00  |
```

I want to get results with conditions like this

- Each `itemN` and `UOM` is unique (GROUP),
- Sort by highest `startDate`,
- if `endDate IS NOT NULL` check if `startDate` AND `endDate` it is still in `CURDATE()`,
- `startDate` is bigger than today 
  So the return should look like:

```
id |itemNo|startDate  |endDate    |UOM  |Price |
---+------+-----------------------+-----+------+
2  |1AY   |2021-02-01 |NULL       |PCS  |3.50  |
5  |3GH   |2019-01-01 |NULL       |TIN  |3.00  |
6  |2ZX   |2021-01-01 |NULL       |BTL  |10.00 |
8  |1AY   |2021-02-01 |NULL       |BOX  |6.50  |
```

This is an example of syntax I made, but it still showing results that don't match what I need. Thanks you

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT itemNo, UOM, MAX(startingDate) AS startingDate FROM d_saleprice_list 
WHERE itemNo IN ('1AY', '2ZX', '3GH')
GROUP BY itemNo, UOM)
AS x JOIN d_saleprice_list USING (itemNo, UOM, startingDate) 
WHERE 
IF (endingDate IS NOT NULL, CURDATE() BETWEEN startingDate and endingDate, 1=1)
AND CURDATE() >= startingDate;
```

Comment: What queries have you already attempted, and what output are you getting from those?  I believe the purpose of StackOverflow is not just to get someone to write your entire query for you, but to assist you with effort that you have already done and advise where you should look at making changes.  You should first endeavour to do some research and attempt to produce your required output

Comment: @Craig thnk u for your advice. I have already update my question there

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT id, v.ItemNo, v.startingDate, v.endingDate, v.UOM, v.Price
FROM
(SELECT itemNo, UOM, 
        MAX(startingDate) AS startingDate
  FROM d_saleprice_list 
  WHERE itemNo IN ('1AY', '2ZX', '3GH')
  AND endingDate IS NULL
  AND startingDate <= CURDATE()
 GROUP BY itemNo, UOM 
) AS x 
JOIN d_saleprice_list AS v
USING (itemNo, UOM, startingDate);
```

These two conditions are confusing .. *"if endDate IS NOT NULL check if startDate AND endDate it is still in CURDATE()"* and *"startDate is bigger than today"* .. because if those are added, the expected result won't be achieved.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8d2907ec45d8c94ddff0da737781994